# How to change property values in an array Object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to change the values of each property in an array using a **forEach** function but not having any luck.

**Here's my array:**

```
  this.panels = [
  { isRandomPanel  : false },
  { isMyPanel  : false },
  { isFavorite      : false },
  { isEatable : false }
  ]
```

I'm trying to update the value of each property to **true** so finally I can get this:

```
 isRandomPanel = true
 isMyPanel  = true
 isFavorite = true
 isEatable = true
```

I'm trying to use the forEach function but I'm stuck:

```
   this.panels.forEach(panel => panel.isRandomPanel = true);
```

Does anyone know how to make this happen using pure Javascript, TypeScript or ES6?

Comment: Are those the only keys on the objects? If so, you can iterate over `Object.keys(panel)` and set each `panel[key] = true`

Comment: `isEdible` ... if you can eat something, it's "edible." Aside from that, Why the separate objects for each key? Wouldn't you instead want an array of panel objects that each contain all of these individual flags set to either true or false? If there's only 1 panel, you don't need an array. If there are multiple panels, your structure above is odd. Do you only add/set those properties once they're true? In that case you might wind up dealing w/null or undefined values for the missing properties.

Comment: Just to make it clear, this is not JSON array. This is array of JS objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are the only keys on the objects, you can iterate over `Object.keys(panel)` and set each `panel[key] = true`, like so:

```js
var panels = [
  { isRandomPanel  : false },
  { isMyPanel  : false },
  { isFavorite      : false },
  { isEatable : false }
];

// set all panel flags to true
panels.forEach(function (panel) {
  Object.keys(panel).forEach(function (key) {
    panel[key] = true;
  });
});

console.log(panels);
```

Or, with shortened ES6 Syntax:

```
panels.forEach(panel => Object.keys(panel).forEach(key => panel[key] = true));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to itreate over the array, get each key from the object and set the value of that key to true. You can use `Object.keys` or `for in` loop to get the keys:

```
this.panels.forEach(panel => {
  for(const key of Object.keys(panel))
    panel[key] = true
})
```

OR

```
this.panels.forEach(panel => {
  for(const key in panel)
    panel[key] = true
})
```

Comment: It is good practice that if you use `for...in`, you should be using the corresponding `panel.hasOwnProperty(key)` check.

Comment: `for in` gets all the keys of object itself and its `prototype` parent as well. So its a good practice to check the direct properties by `hasOwnProperty`

Answer (score -1):

As you are using ES 6, So following will work

`panels.forEach(panel => Object.keys(panel).forEach(key => panel[key] = true));`